# Array of objects is empty when I transform it to json

Tags: javascript, arrays, async-await, spotify

The object has an array of objects

```
songs = {"items": [{...},{...}]};
```

After mapping and filling this array with values from api calls, I can console log and see all the items I want store in that array, but when I use this array in another function or log the array size, in both cases the array is empty.

I know this issue is related to the api calls and asynchronicity, but I couldn't solve it.

The context code:

```
const getArrayOfSongs = (playlists, dataFavorites, dataProfile, accessToken) => {
    let songs = {"items": []};
     playlists.map((playlist) => {
        axios
             .get(PLAYLIST_ENDPOINT + playlist.id + "/tracks?limit=50&offset=0", {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
                },
            })
            .then((response) => {
                response.data.items.map((song) => {
                    if (song.track.is_local === false) {

                        let artists = [];
                        const cutArtist = () => { song.track.artists.forEach((artist) => artists.push(artist.name)) }
                        cutArtist();

                        const obj = { "name": song.track.name, "id": song.track.id, "album": song.track.album.name, "artist": artists, "link": song.track.href };

                        const index = songs.items.findIndex(object => object.id === obj.id);
                        if (index === -1) {
                            songs.items.push(obj);
                        }
                    }
                });

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    });

    //shows me everything
    console.log(songs.items)

    //shows me 0 value
    console.log(songs.items.length)

    const user = getProfile(dataProfile);

    //array is empty
    sendSongs(JSON.stringify(songs), user);
}
```

Comment: use promises and/or await/async

Comment: *"shows me everything"*: it only shows you everything when you expand the visualisation in the console. By the time you do that, the array has been populated.

Comment: `const responses = await Promise.all(playlists.map(playlist => axios.get(...)));`